# Unity change size of cube mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resize, mesh, bounds

Does Unity have methods to change mesh's width, height and depth?
I know there would be the way to change mesh vertices. Like A vertice = -5,0,0 and B vertice = 5,0,0 so length would be 10. But that's is hard way. Is it a easy way?

I tried to do:

```
lorry.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.size.Set(1000F, 200F, 200F);
```

but nothing changed. I don't even understand what for is `bound.size.set()`
because when i call `Debug.Log(lorry.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.size);`
it returns (1,1,1)

I tried to call

`lorry.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.RecalculateBounds();`

But result is same.

Comment: you really need to change "mesh vertices" positions, or it's okay to scale the mesh?

Comment: better would be change mesh vertices

Comment: point is that i want to make a box, like a container. And i have to add boxes with different dimensions in it. And i need to check if box bounds doesn't go outside container.  and with  Bound functions i could achieve that easy and accurately

Comment: I think that changing bounds won't work (there shouldn't be even option to change it). Bounds are calculated based on mesh, not mesh based on bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems Unity doesn't provide easy way to resize mesh. So i made an extension:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Extensions {
    public static void recalculateMeshByBounds(this Mesh mesh, Vector3 dimensions) {

        mesh.Clear();

        float length = dimensions.x / 2;
        float height = dimensions.y / 2;
        float width  = dimensions.z / 2;

        #region Vertices
        Vector3 p0 = new Vector3(-length, -width,  height);
        Vector3 p1 = new Vector3( length, -width,  height);
        Vector3 p2 = new Vector3( length, -width, -height);
        Vector3 p3 = new Vector3(-length, -width, -height);

        Vector3 p4 = new Vector3(-length, width,  height);
        Vector3 p5 = new Vector3( length, width,  height);
        Vector3 p6 = new Vector3( length, width, -height);
        Vector3 p7 = new Vector3(-length, width, -height);

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            // Bottom
            p0, p1, p2, p3,

            // Left
            p7, p4, p0, p3,

            // Front
            p4, p5, p1, p0,

            // Back
            p6, p7, p3, p2,

            // Right
            p5, p6, p2, p1,

            // Top
            p7, p6, p5, p4
        };
        #endregion

        #region Normales
        Vector3 up = Vector3.up;
        Vector3 down = Vector3.down;
        Vector3 front = Vector3.forward;
        Vector3 back = Vector3.back;
        Vector3 left = Vector3.left;
        Vector3 right = Vector3.right;

        Vector3[] normales = new Vector3[]
        {
            // Bottom
            down, down, down, down,

            // Left
            left, left, left, left,

            // Front
            front, front, front, front,

            // Back
            back, back, back, back,

            // Right
            right, right, right, right,

            // Top
            up, up, up, up
        };
        #endregion

        #region UVs
        Vector2 _00 = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
        Vector2 _10 = new Vector2(1f, 0f);
        Vector2 _01 = new Vector2(0f, 1f);
        Vector2 _11 = new Vector2(1f, 1f);

        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[]
        {
            // Bottom
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Left
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Front
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Back
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Right
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Top
            _11, _01, _00, _10,
        };
        #endregion

        #region Triangles
        int[] triangles = new int[]
        {
            // Bottom
            3, 1, 0,
            3, 2, 1,            

            // Left
            3 + 4 * 1, 1 + 4 * 1, 0 + 4 * 1,
            3 + 4 * 1, 2 + 4 * 1, 1 + 4 * 1,

            // Front
            3 + 4 * 2, 1 + 4 * 2, 0 + 4 * 2,
            3 + 4 * 2, 2 + 4 * 2, 1 + 4 * 2,

            // Back
            3 + 4 * 3, 1 + 4 * 3, 0 + 4 * 3,
            3 + 4 * 3, 2 + 4 * 3, 1 + 4 * 3,

            // Right
            3 + 4 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 0 + 4 * 4,
            3 + 4 * 4, 2 + 4 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4,

            // Top
            3 + 4 * 5, 1 + 4 * 5, 0 + 4 * 5,
            3 + 4 * 5, 2 + 4 * 5, 1 + 4 * 5,

        };
        #endregion

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.normals = normales;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.MarkDynamic();


    }
}
```

**Usage:** 
 Add Box primitive to scene. 
 Create Script and drag into Box:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Box: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 dimensions;   

    private void Start()
    {

        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.recalculateMeshByBounds(dimensions);
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And now you can access to dimensions `Vector3 dimensions(length, height, width).` And when you change values, vertice's vectors also changes. Maybe there is better way, but until now i found easiest way for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the size of a gameObject in runtime you can change the scale. For example to double the size of the GameObject:

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(2F, 2F, 2F);
```

Edit based on your comment:

*point is that i want to make a box, like a container. And i have to add boxes with different dimensions in it. And i need to check if box bounds doesn't go outside container.*

For this you may be interested in using a box collider which doesnt require a mesh. Then you can set the size of the collider like:

```
BoxCollider boxCol;

void Awake(){
    boxCol = otherGameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
}

void Start(){
    //Here you set the size of the collider
    boxCol.size = new Vector3(2,2,2);
}
```

Comment: Ignacio check the comments, Marius don't want to change the scale, just the mesh vertices positions

Comment: @Lotan Thanks for poiting out. I replied with a possible approach without touching the vertex of the mesh, which I am not sure if it is possible to access them independently from a script

Comment: Thanks for replay, but checking with colliders is a bad idea. Because collider only return bool.

Comment: @Marius But I understand you only want to check if a box go outside container. That is a yes/no condition. What other information do you need then?

Comment: If box is in container, then always return true. And for example if half box is outside container it will return true again. Thats why i need bounds to check if some of box is outside

Comment: @Marius What I had in mind is a collision enter, but it may not work neither, I cannot test it right now. I will keep thinking, in case I don't come up with a useful approach I will delete the answer later, since so far is not addressing your question.

Comment: Changing the scale is a horrible recommendation, because it does not align with engine units. Downvoting.